# What can we conclude from $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, problem-solving

I am solving CMI PHD questions.One of the questions from real analysis is as follows:

**Question**

Let $f:\mathbb {R\to R}$ be a function such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$,then which of the following are true:

$(a) f$ is bounded.

$(b)f$ is bounded if it is continuous.

$(c)f$ is differentiable if it is continuous.

$(d)f$ is uniformly continuous if it is continuous.

My answer to this question is as follows:

Take $f(x)=\sec(2\pi x)$ and assign $0$ value to points where it is undefined to show that $(a)$ is false.Then $(b)$ is true because $f$ is $1$-periodic and hence $f(\mathbb R)=f([0,1])$ which is bounded if $f$ is continuous.For disproving $(c)$ take the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{2} |x|$ on $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ and replicate it periodically on $\mathbb R$.Finally $(d)$ is true because any periodic continuous function is uniformly continuous.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Does $\sec(2\pi x)$ count since it's not defined everywhere? Do you just extend it to be anything on the gaps?

Comment: @Keshav I have made an edit.Now see if it is ok.

Comment: (d) sounds like you are saying "d is true because d is true"

Comment: @DanielV It is a well-known result.I can send you the proof.

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me

Comment: Function is periodic with period as 1.

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: @DanielV. I was going to say that.  A detailed argument for (d): For $r>0$ let $0<s<1$ such that $\forall x,y\in [0,2]\,(|x-y|<s\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<r).$ Now for any $x,y,$ if $|x-y|<s$ then there exists $n\in \Bbb Z$ with $x-n,y-n\in [0,2].$ Et cetera.